# VideoView "Can't play video"

Tags: android

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    String uriPath = (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "MyVideo.3gp");

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    mVideoView.requestFocus();
    mVideoView.start();
}
```

Main xml

```
    <VideoView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

what's wrong with my code? I can play the video through storage but won't run on my app

Comment: Any error messages? Try `setOnErrorListener` on the VideoView and post what you get in `onError` callback.

Comment: Change your uri path to   Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/MyVideo.3gp");

Comment: or v.setVideoPath("/sdcard/MyVideo.3gp");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String uriPath = (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "MyVideo.3gp");
```

I think it must be a wrong path reference.

P.S: Not sure if File.separator is necessary.

Comment: this seemed to fix it. i figure it was because i was saving the file using io.file .  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Video View If You get "Can't play video" message  than it occurs because of any of below reasons:

**1) If your file format is Unsupported**

**2) If your file codecs are Unsupported**

**3) If your file contains any internal Error**

**4) Forgot `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in manifes**